# Euclid's lemma for non-prime numbers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

I was trying to prove that $\sqrt{6}$ irrational as:

Let $$\sqrt{6}=\dfrac ab$$
    $$\implies a^2=6b^2$$ 
    $$6|a^2 \implies 6|a$$.

I should not be able to do the step because 6 is not a prime number, hence it does not satisfies the Euclid's lemma. But somehow "6 divides a" seems to be valid. If $6|a^2$ then $a^2$ must have both 3 and 2 as its factors, and this is only possible when $a$ itself has 3 and 2 as its factors.

I also noted that $k|a^2 \nRightarrow k|a $ only when $k$ is a complete square, e.g. $4|2^2$ but $4 \nmid 2$.

> **Question**
>   Am I correct in saying, "6 divides $a^2 \implies $6 divides $a$"?
>   Is this some theorem, if yes what is it called?

Comment: if $$6|a \Rightarrow 2|a ,3|a $$

Comment: It's not really a theorem or lemma because the situation is too specific to have its own rule. The point is that 6 is square-free. If you take any other number $n$ where the primes in its factorization occur only with the power 1, then $n| a^2 \Rightarrow n|a$.

Comment: For example it also works for 5.7.11=385 instead of 6.

Comment: @daryakhosrotash I understand that $6|a⇒2|a,3|a$. Am I missing something else?

Comment: I do apologize , but  ,I mean start with $$ 2|a \Rightarrow a=2k \Rightarrow (2k)^2=6b^2 \Rightarrow$$ so b must be in form of b=2q $$ and b/a is not rational

Answer (score 3):

$3$ divides $a^2$ $\implies$ 3 divides $a$.

$2$ divides $a^2$ $\implies$ 2 divides $a$.

$2\cdot 3$ divides $a$.

Comment: $a^2=2\cdot 3 b^2 \implies$ $a^2$ is divisible by both $2$ and $3$ and so is $a$.